# Variable into class name

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put variable into name of class and after hours of searching I haven't found answer.
This is my code. I want to put var `i` to class `red_val` to have `red_val1` and then `red_val2` etc.
If anyone could help me that would be great!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
        i++;
        $('<div id="red_val"[+i]>ss</div><div id=red></div><div id=green></div><div id=blue></div>').appendTo('.container');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;

    $('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
            $('<div id="red_val'+i+'">ss</div><div id="red'+i+'"></div><div id="green'+i+'"></div><div id="blue'+i+'"></div>').appendTo('.container');
            $( "#red"+i, "#green"+i, "#blue"+i ).slider({ orientation: "horizontal", range: "min", max: 255, value: 127, slide: refreshSwatch, change: refreshSwatch });
            i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Rafał - thanks... Might be you have missed single quote/double quote while trying that...!

Comment: How can I do exactly the same but in here:

`$( "#red'+i', #green'+i', #blue'+i'" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      value: 127,
      slide: refreshSwatch,
      change: refreshSwatch
    });`

Comment: @Rafał - updated the answer. please have a look at it.